# Linking with GCC and x86 ASM in x64 Environment

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, linker

I am running Windows Ultimate x64 (Core i5), and using the x64 GCC compiler on Cygwin. I wanted to create a simple "Hello, world" program by linking against the GCC C library (installed via Cygwin). I am using NASM and trying both ELF32 and Win32 formats for the following code:

```
;;
;; hello.asm - use the C library to output hello world
;;

; In case I wanted to use the code for Windows later
%if 0
%define main    _main
%define printf  _printf
%endif

global main
extern printf

; we set up our string here
section .data
    formatstr:  db 'hello, world!', 10, 0

section .text

    main:

    sub     esp, 4

    lea     eax, [formatstr]
    mov     [esp], eax
    call    printf

    add     esp, 4
    mov     eax, 0

    ret
```

When using `nasm -f elf32 hello.asm` or `nasm -f win32 hello.asm`, along with `gcc hello.o -o hello`, GCC tells me:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `hello.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My Googling led me to install the cygwin32 package for Cygwin, so I've done that.

When I looked up how to run GCC in 32-bit mode, I added the `m32` switch, but this resulted in more error output for both ELF and Win32:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcygwin
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/            lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm still quite new to assembler and digesting ABIs, so I'm not quite sure how to proceed here. I feel I'm missing something very simple, as I've successfully linked assembler code I've written for a C project in the past.

Comment: I had the same problem before and I gave up and started dual booting Linux. Not suggesting that but hopefully someone could help you out.

Comment: From the looks of [this mailing list post](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-10/msg00312.html), I think you need to be using the 32-bit Cygwin to compile a 32-bit x86 executable.

Comment: I actually run amd64 Ubuntu in VirtualBox and I had the same problems with the ELF32 output. However, I need to double-check if I installed x86 support for GCC.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Adam Rosenfield pointing out the Cygwin mailing list post, I went ahead and tried to rewrite my ASM with x64 support in mind. This did allow me to output a binary with GCC. I should note that my program causes a segmentation fault, but that's an issue of me not really knowing x64 assembler or the respective calling conventions well enough.